# Server side library for conversion of office files to pdf with added stamp/watermark

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-office, watermark, aspose

I need to take Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Visio files and convert them to PDF on the server side using C#.

At some point before or after the PDF conversion, the clients want a stamp/watermark to be added to the corner of the document (assuming, for now, on every page).

I cannot use Office products in the process, as there are licensing and stability issues involved with using "interop" server-side. Also, I would rather not depend on any other installed software on the server for similar reasons; this functionality will be used by multiple clients at the same time.

I have spent a couple of days searching, and 
[Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) seems to be the only library which would be suitable, however it seems prohibitively expensive. I would welcome any suggestions which would complete all requirements, or separate libraries to handle the watermark and conversion to PDF separately

UPDATE: As of now I have a prototype converting all the above file types to pdf with a watermark added using Aspose. It was relatively easy, the forum can be a great help when in a pickly

Answer (score 0):

I think AbcPDF will do this for about half the price: http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-office-docs.htm

You might have to roll the watermark part yourself, but that's quite trivial to code.

There is also quite a list of libs here: [.NET server based PDF generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450833/net-server-based-pdf-generation)

Comment: Hmmm for my uses the licence required for this software would come to nearly 5k, the aspose libraries are nearly worth the extra cost for more functionality (but not quite). Is there a cheaper library anywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure where you get that figure from. Are you running 10 servers in parallel? AbcPdf professional costs about $475 per server (I haven't purchased a license for a while, but it's in that ballpark). We run dozens of clients in parallel from a single server in this way. If what you need is OEM functionality (ie. embedding the library in a client), then sure, that will stack up with any component, but I understood you were working on the server side?

Comment: I will be implementing it as part of a much larger piece of software which we sell to clients to put on their 64bit servers, which in my understanding means the need for a redistributable licence, hence the figure. http://www.websupergoo.com/purchase.htm#abcpdfnetI am still considering this option however, ill have to see what the bosses think. I have spotted this http://www.cete.com/Products/DynamicPDFConverterforNET/ which might handle the pdf conversion and like you say do the watermarking myself

Comment: Redistribution licenses are pretty steep (and justifiably so: you would want a fair chunk of income from something that's sold over and over again). I have worked with DynamicPDF before, a long time ago, and I remember it being a solid library. We use PDFLib these days, which is the best one I've come across, but is priced accordingly. If cost is a real issue, why not go the SOA route and put your PDF functionality into a web service that all your clients access in the cloud?

Comment: Price isn't a huge issue, the bosses want to maximize profit I suppose, i'm just doing what im told. RE. SOA route i did suggest that to them but they are dismissed it.We were veering towards Aspose.Total because of all the extra functionality it has accross the office document board, but cracks are starting to show; the OCR library seems very inneffective, it doesnt truly come with a word viewer, despite it alluding to that on the website and its doesnt have much support for content containers or smartart.

Comment: http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-8.htm - "ABCpdf can read a variety of document formats when helper applications like OpenOffice.org are installed". Does this mean ABCpdf uses OpenOffice interop for conversion of office formats to PDF?

Comment: It seems that way. Note that they are only talking about the older binary file formats. Presumably you would need to implement your own conversion for the newer .**x formats, but since they are XML-based that oughtn't to be too hard.