# Can I design a word document on PC then edit and convert to PDF on IIS using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

Here is what I would like to do:

- Create a template/document that looks like I want with page border, logo image, structured areas, preformatted and positioned text, etc. I am thinking this would be a word document but am open to anything.  I just need to be able to design the document to specifics provided by the customer.  I plan on doing this on a PC by hand before uploading to the server.
- Store it on the server or in a database for future retrieval (got this covered).
- When needed, access the template/document and programatically add data into the document in predetermined locations (such as name, address, phone, products purchased, amount financed, etc).
- Convert the document to PDF.
- Email the document (got this covered).

I am doing all this with C# and ASP.NET/MVC.  Can you recommend libraries and possibly supporting tutorials/wiki/documentation to accomplish this?

Comment: I use NPOI for Excel document manipulation.  You can both read/write data.  http://npoi.codeplex.com/  For PDF manipulation ghostscript is quite nice, but it generally inputs/outputs images and text not Excel.  There is a related topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140452/server-side-library-for-conversion-of-office-files-to-pdf-with-added-stamp-water  certainly pdflib (which I also use) with NPOI could allow you to manually write the conversion...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: You can do anything you set your mind to. That being said, look into third party libraries.

Comment: Am I approaching this problem correctly?  Or must I generate the document completely through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a very similar thing as you're describing however it was more of a merging and splitting of pdf files with only minor content modification but I found that PDFSharp worked very well.  Definitely worth looking at for your purposes.  [PDFSharp.net][1]

[1]: http://PDFSharp.net  - and it's open source...

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of paid third party libraries that do this. I have used one such (http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm#pd) and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this using the following:

1. Generate Word document: Use `System.Xml` to output Word document using the Word's XML Markup: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212889(v=office.11).aspx

   ```
   // Simple document setup
   XmlTextWriter Writer = new XmlTextWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../XMLDocs/") + FileName + ".doc", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
   Writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
   Writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:wordDocument");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:w", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns:wx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint");
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:styles");
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:style");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:type", "paragraph");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:default", "on");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:styleId", "Paragraph");
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:name");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:val", "Paragraph");
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:rPr");
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:sz");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:val", "18");
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();

   // Simple document editing
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:p");
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:pPr");
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:pStyle");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:val", "Paragraph");
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:r");
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:t");
   Writer.WriteRaw("Some Text");
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();

   // Simple document completion
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:sectPr");
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:pgSz");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:w", "12240");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:h", "15840");
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:pgMar");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:top", "1440");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:right", "1440");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:bottom", "1440");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:left", "1440");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:header", "720");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:footer", "720");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:gutter", "0");
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:cols");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:space", "720");
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteStartElement("w:docGrid");
   Writer.WriteAttributeString("w:line-pitch", "360");
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.WriteEndElement();
   Writer.Close();
   ```
2. Convert to PDF: Silent printing via command line arguments to SumatraPDF with a virtual printer attached: https://code.google.com/p/sumatrapdf/wiki/CommandLineArguments

   ```
   var flagPrintToPrinter = String.Format("-print-to \"{0}\"", printerName);
   var flagSilentAndSuppressErrors = "-silent";

   var args = String.Format("{0} {1} \"{2}\"", flagPrintToPrinter, flagSilentAndSuppressErrors, printFileName);
   var currentDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

   var process = new Process
   {
     StartInfo = {FileName = String.Format(@"{0}\ThirdPartyAssemblies\SumatraPDF.exe", currentDirectory), Arguments = args}
   };

   process.Start();
   process.WaitForExit();
   var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
   process.Close();
   ```