# Asp.Net MVC filecontentresult error generating pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, pdf

Controller:

```
    <HttpGet>
Function downloadpdf() As FileContentResult

    Dim data As MyData = Me.Getdata()
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    If data IsNot Nothing Then
        If data.HasItems Then
            sb.AppendLine()
            sb.AppendLine("ID,Description)
            For Each item In data.Items
                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0},{1}", item.Id, item.Description))
            Next
        End If
    End If
    Dim bytes as Byte() = New UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sb.ToString())
    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=mypdf.pdf")
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString())
    Return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "mypdf.pdf")

End Function
```

View:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("downloadpdf", "home")">PDF</a>
```

When clicked the link, it prompt to download the file, then it display this:

Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 'mypdf.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

And the pdf doesn't open.
Any suggestion or any other way to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way you create a PDF. You are just returning a text file with a PDF extension.

You will need a third party tool to create a PDF. I use [ABCPdf](https://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) (Paid, I'm not affiliated to them), but there are several [open](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/) [source](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) [tools](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/index.html) to choose from.

Related: [.NET server based PDF generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450833/net-server-based-pdf-generation)